# Do fully enlightened "persons" still meditate, and why?

Tags: buddhas, arhats

Do fully enlightened "persons" still meditate, and why? I get why they keep living, to help sentient beings. But does meditation help in that way?

Comment: sorry for that, my mistake

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Buddha did meditate. This is for the pleasant abiding here and now.

From the discussion, [What did Buddha do to pass his time?](https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=20345&hilit=) --

> Some relevant info:
>
> > Then the Blessed One, having emerged from seclusion after the passing of
> >     three months, addressed the monks: “Monks, if wanderers of other sects
> >     ask you, ‘By means of what dwelling, friends, did Gotama the
> >     contemplative mostly dwell during the rains residence?’: You, thus asked,
> >     should answer them in this way: ‘It was by means of the concentration of
> >     mindfulness of breathing that the Blessed One mostly dwelled.’ …
>
> This means that right mindfulness functions not only as a factor of the path,
>   but also as a pleasant pastime for those who have fully developed the path and
>   tasted its ultimate fruit.

This quote is originally from the [Icchānaṅgala Sutta  (SN 54:11)](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN54_11.html).

Comment: do we know why the buddha meditated?

Comment: He is not deliberately meditating like a beginner. Meditation is his natural relaxed state when he is not occupied with anything else.